# Extracting year after converting to a date having issues in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I have a column  which is of String data type but holds a date value. I converted it to a DATE and then extracted the YEAR from it using the below format in POSTGRESQL.
However, if I try to get the last 10 year data, I see that any date that is lesser than the last 50 years ( i.e less than 1970 , takes up the format of 2069, 2068 and so on). Lets say there is a date value in the format (10/1/58, it gets listed inspite of giving the filter for the last 10 years as 2058)

I used the below for converting to DATE and extracting the year

```
extract YEAR FROM  TO_DATE(release_date,'MM/DD/YY')
```

Then used the below condition in my query to get the last 10 year data

```
 where  extract(year from current_timestamp)-EXTRACT(YEAR FROM  TO_DATE(release_date,'MM/DD/YY')) <=10
```

How to solve this in POSTGRESQL

Comment: Use `'MM/DD/YYYY` instead of `'MM/DD/YY'`. Per docs here [Data formatting](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-formatting.html): 'In to_timestamp and to_date, if the year format specification is less than four digits, e.g., YYY, and the supplied year is less than four digits, the year will be adjusted to be nearest to the year 2020, e.g., 95 becomes 1995.'

Comment: I dont have problems with 1995 . Its the years less than 1970 .Year 12/12/69 shows up as 2069 . I tried using MM/DD/YYYY but see only 69 being returned

Comment: What a bad idea to store a date as a string. And with only two digits for the year even. You cannot expect the DBMS to guess the century right. It's not a human being who knows its 1843 when told that Dickens wrote A Christmas Carol in '43. So you must adjust the DBMS's guesses. As it seems you want it to be in the past 100 years until now, use `CASE WHEN` on the year and subtract 100 years when necessary. (And then you should change the column's data type to `DATE` in order to avoid such problems in the future.)

Comment: What you are facing was the solution to the Y2K problem (22 ago). Some 2digit year was selected as a pivotal year, for Postgres looks like that value now stands at 70. Any value less that that is the prior century, any number equal or greater the current century.  Solution: as @AdrianKlaver suggested use a 4digit year, or the ISO Standard format `DATE yyyy-mm-dd`  (ecample 1DATE '2072-01-01'`

Answer (score 1):

Well:

```
select extract(year from current_timestamp);
date_part 
-----------
      2021

select EXTRACT(YEAR FROM  TO_DATE('10/1/58','MM/DD/YYYY'));
 date_part 
-----------
        58

select 2021 - 58;
 ?column? 
----------
     1963

1963 ! <= 10
```

Your best bet would be to clean up the date data by turning `YY` into YYYY`and better yet by storing in a`date` field instead of as a string.

Answer (score 1):

As this is documented behaviour

use a function to determine the year

> ```
> CREATE TABLE mytable(release_date varchar(20))
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO mytable VALUES ('01/01/69'),('01/01/70')
> ```

> ```
> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION corectyear(inyear integer) RETURNS integer AS $$
> DECLARE curyear INTEGER;
>         BEGIN
>         SELECT extract( YEAR FROM  CURRENT_DATE) INTO curyear;
>         IF inyear > curyear THEN
>           RETURN inyear - 100;
>         ELSE
>            RETURN inyear;
>         END IF;
>                 
>         END;
> $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
> ```

> ```
> SELECt corectyear(extract( YEAR FROM  TO_DATE(release_date,'MM/DD/YY'))::INTEGER) FROM mytable
> ```
>
> ```
> | corectyear |
> | ---------: |
> |       1969 |
> |       1970 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=cb96783d9eedd9678e34116501693703)*